# Browser Console debugging for AnugularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Ok! fine as we might be aware of that we also user browser Console for debugging and development of Apps Related to Javascript, Jquery etc...

But coming to point of Angular feeling big difference while debugging.

like getting elements,Objects.
Browser Console came very handy for jQuery.
Any Good documentation, article for development using browser console.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @VVK my question was how to debug more efficiently using Browser Console for AngularJS, which i Clearly specified in my question.

Comment: i like debugging in Firefox (firebug). it has a good structure

Answer (score 0):

**Angular Batarang**

Angular Batarang is a Chrome extension developed by the Angular team at Google that integrates very nicely as a debugging tool for Angular apps.

To install Batarang, we simply need to download the application from the web store or from the GitHub repo: [angular Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang).

Once our installation is set, we can start up the extension by navigating to our developer tools and clicking enable to enable Batarang to start collecting debugging information about our page.

Batarang allows us to look at scopes, performance, dependencies, and other key metrics in Angular apps.

**ng-inspector for AngularJS**

Firebug and Google chrome developer are great for catching errors. ng-inspector can be used to view data returned by the application. ng-inspector works in Google chrome, Firefox and safari. You can download it from the official website [ng-inspector](http://www.ng-inspector.org)